# jQuery binding to parent element click event from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I posted a similar question earlier and received an answer, which I was able to only get partially working before running into a new issue.

This is the code within `$(document).ready()` in my iframe:

```
$("button#arrow-left", window.parent.document).on("click", function () {
    console.log("Got here");
    $(document).trigger("VEHICLE.CONTROLS.PRESSED_LEFT");
});
```

This almost works.  I get "Got here" dumped into my console now when I click the left arrow on my parent document.  However, as far as I can tell the "VEHICLE.CONTROLS.PRESSED_LEFT" event is never firing.

In another part of my iframe JavaScript, I have the lines:

```
$(document).on("VEHICLE.CONTROLS.PRESSED_LEFT", function () {
    console.log("Left button pressed, triggering left swipe.");
    $("div#swipe-container").swipe('swipe_left');
});
```

That second console log never happens, and my swipe plugin doesn't execute a left swipe as it should.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

In case it's relevant, I'm basically taking an HTML5/JS app built to run in a vehicle and porting it to the browser.  The app itself is running in an iframe, and the parent document has some simulated vehicle controls.

I know I could bind directly to the button click within that area of my code that triggers the swipe, but the idea is that I have a single JS file acting as the medium between the application and the target API.  This way I can keep the code in sync regardless of whether it's running in the actual vehicle, or just my simulator.

Edit:  Also, this was almost the same functionality that I had working before using the actual vehicle API.  An example of how I set up controls previously when using the vehicle API:

```
sdk.vehicle.watchButtons("left", function () {
    $(document).trigger("VEHICLE.CONTROLS.PRESSED_LEFT");
});
```